# How to make sure sqlite DB gets updated during app update?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, app-store

I have an application on app-store which is DB driven, mean all the content is residing in the sqlite DB file. Now, I need to send another update of the app with some content update in the sqlite DB, so, What's the simplest way to make it sure that my DB gets updated during app update. Note that it's static app and there's no online services included to sync DB so I am looking for something simple, without involvement of server side services etc. Awaiting response. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a copy of your database to somewhere like the Caches folder, you should add an extra table to the database with an entry for the database version. Add something like `2011-11-23` as a string or date to a "db_version" entry. When you update the database, update that field. When your app starts, check the app bundle version of the database against the copied database. If the app bundle version is newer, copy it  after deleting the old one.

If the database file is used from the app bundle without being copied, you don't need to do anything. The old version will be deleted when the app is updated.

Comment: I did make the check and replaced the DB with the newer one. Now I need some code to copy some user tables from my previous DB before replacing it with the new one...Any help with that?

Comment: You'll need to keep the old database around while you copy the data. I'm not certain how it would work, but you could probably open up two connections to the databases, then use SQL to get the user tables, and use SQL to insert it into the new table. It might be easier to consider using a completely separate table for user data to avoid this. Be careful about the situation where the data transfer is interrupted half-way.

Comment: ya.. I was thinking along those lines too. anyways I got a quick way around for my problem.. Thinking to implement something which make my life easier for such problems in future;).. like some class which copies the mentioned DB tables before replacing the DB.